# What do I (pro tem moderator) do about indiscriminate voting?

Tags: discussion, voting, moderation

On Quant SE, a user has been blindly upvoting some of the top users. Specifically, he has been maxing-out his daily vote limit by upvoting *every answer* from a small pool of users. I [warned this user](https://quant.meta.stackexchange.com/q/131/35) last week, but that didn't seem to stop the "vote stuffing".

I think this is a problem because the fraud detector could cancel the votes, which means that the reputations will swing wildly. Is there a protocol for handling a user like this?

Comment: Just pass [Jeff's](http://meta.quant.stackexchange.com/questions/131/reputation-manipulation-take-two/134#134) message to them - *"Just make sure when you vote, you vote for lots of great content -- not the same user over and over."* Isn't it enough?

Comment: When in doubt, suspend for a month